Help locally to Sussex with our Oracle DB ORA-01653: unable to extend table SYS.WARNING_SETTINGS$ by 8 in tablespace SYSTEM
Hope you can help?
Help remotely with our Oracle.
We have had this message
DB ORA-01653: unable to extend table SYS.WARNING_SETTINGS$ by 8 in tablespace SYSTEM
If you can support us to repair this / guidance on how we can extend the size of the DB and enable the database restore as this no longer works?

From oracle docs: Depending on the tablespace attributes and storage strategy, take one of the following actions:
Resize the tablespace using either the ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE RESIZE or ALTER TABLESPACE ADD DATAFILE statement.

Enable AUTOEXTEND for the tablespace.

If AUTOEXTEND is already enabled:
And MAXSIZE is set to UNLIMITED, increase the storage media where the tablespace is located.
Increase MAXSIZE.

If it is a BIGFILE tablespace, use the ALTER TABLESPACE RESIZE 

statement to increase the tablespace.
This assumes that you know how to login as an administrator and perform one of these actions. Tell us if you do not.

Thank you - this was most helpful
